# Tring to Remove Comma Before or During Parsing CSV in ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I am importing a CSV File that is being Parsed and i have the seperators set to "|" i would like to remove the comma's or comment them so they do not mess up colums

Here is the part that i think should have a code to remove the ,'s

```
namespace :postonce do
  desc "Check postonce ftp files and post loads and trucks."
  task :post => :environment do
    files = %x[ls /home/web2_postonce/].split("\n")
    files.each do |file|
      %x[ iconv -t UTF-8 /home/web2_postonce/#{file} > /home/deployer/postonce/#{file} ]
      %x[ mv /home/web2_postonce/#{file} /home/deployer/postonce_backup/ ]
    end
    files = %x[ ls /home/deployer/postonce/ ].split("\n")
    files.each do |file|
      begin
        lines = CSV.read("/home/deployer/postonce/#{file}")
      rescue Exception => e
        log.error e
        next
      end
      h = lines.shift
      header = CSV.parse_line(h[0], { :col_sep => "|" } )
      lines.each do |line|
        fields = CSV.parse_line(line[0],{:col_sep => "|"})
        post = Hash[header.zip fields]
     if post["EmailAddress"].blank?
       log.error "Blank Email #{post["EmailAddress"]}"
        else
       log.debug "Email #{post["EmailAddress"]}"
        end
```

Here is the the full code that pulls the file and parses the file into colums

```
require 'resque'
require 'logger'
log = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/PostOnce.log")
log.datetime_format = "%F %T"
namespace :postonce do
  desc "Check postonce ftp files and post loads and trucks."
  task :post => :environment do
    files = %x[ls /home/web2_postonce/].split("\n")
    files.each do |file|
      %x[ iconv -t UTF-8 /home/web2_postonce/#{file} > /home/deployer/postonce/#{file} ]
      %x[ mv /home/web2_postonce/#{file} /home/deployer/postonce_backup/ ]
    end
    files = %x[ ls /home/deployer/postonce/ ].split("\n")
    files.each do |file|
      begin
        lines = CSV.read("/home/deployer/postonce/#{file}")
      rescue Exception => e
        log.error e
        next
      end
      h = lines.shift
      header = CSV.parse_line(h[0], { :col_sep => "|" } )
      lines.each do |line|
        fields = CSV.parse_line(line[0],{:col_sep => "|"})
        post = Hash[header.zip fields]
     if post["EmailAddress"].blank?
       log.error "Blank Email #{post["EmailAddress"]}"
        else
       log.error "Email #{post["EmailAddress"]}"
        end
        if post["Notes"].blank?
          post["Notes"] = "~PostOnce~"
        else
          post["Notes"] = post["Notes"]+" ~PostOnce~" 
        end
        if Company.where(:name => post["Company"]).first.nil?
          c = Company.new
          c.name = post["Company"]
          c.dispatch = post["Customer_Phone"]
          c.save
        end
        if User.where(:email => ["EmailAddress"]).first.blank?
          u = User.new
          c = Company.where(:name => post["Company"]).first unless Company.where(:name => post["Company"]).first.nil?
          u.company_id = c.id
          u.username = post["EmailAddress"].gsub(/@.*/,"") unless post["EmailAddress"].nil?
          u.password = Time.now.to_s
          u.email = post["EmailAddress"]
          u.dispatch = post["Customer_Phone"]
          u.save
        end
        #If Load
        if file.start_with?("PO_loads")
          record = Hash.new
          begin
            record[:user_id] = User.where(:email => post["EmailAddress"]).first.id
          rescue Exception => e
            log.error e
            next
          end
          record[:origin] = "#{post["Starting_City"]}, #{post["Starting_State"]}"
          record[:dest] = "#{post["Destination_City"]}, #{post["Destination_State"]}"
          record[:pickup] = Time.parse(post["Pickup_Date_Time"])
          record[:ltl] = false
          record[:ltl] = true unless post["#Load_Type_Full"] = "FULL"
          begin
            record[:equipment_id] = Equipment.where(:code => post["Type_of_Equipment"]).first.id
          rescue Exception => e
            record[:equipment_id] = 34
          end
          record[:comments] = post["Notes"]
          record[:weight] = post["Weight"] 
          record[:length] = post["Length"]
          record[:rate] = post["Payment_amount"]
          record[:rate] = '' if post["Payment_amount"] == 'Call' or post["Payment_amount"] == 'CALL'
          Resque.enqueue(MajorPoster, record) 
        #If Truck
        elsif file.start_with?("PO_trucks")
          record = Hash.new
          begin
            record[:user_id] = User.where(:email => post["EmailAddress"]).first.id
          rescue Exception => e
            log.error e
            next
          end
          record[:origin] = "#{post["Starting_City"]}, #{post["Starting_State"]}"
          record[:dest] = "#{post["Destination_City"]}, #{post["Destination_State"]}"
          record[:available] = Time.parse(post["Pickup_Date_Time"])
          record[:expiration] = record[:available] + 8.days
          begin
            record[:equipment_id] = Equipment.where(:code => post["Type_of_Equipment"]).first.id
          rescue Exception => e
            record[:equipment_id] = 34
          end
          record[:comments] = post["Notes"]
          Resque.enqueue(MajorPoster, record) 
        end
      end
    #  %x[rm /home/deployer/postonce/#{file}]
    end
  end
end
```

here is a sample of data that i am tring to load up the commas come in Customer_Contact and in Notes this data comes to us thru FTP

```
Member_ID|Action_type|Entry_Number|Pickup_Date_Time|Starting_City|Starting_State|Destination_City|Destination_State|Type_of_Equipment|Length|Quantity|#Load_type_full|Extra_Stops|Payment_amount|Weight|Distance|Notes|Customer_Phone|Extension|Customer_Contact|EmailAddress|Company|
SUMMIT|L-delete|16491978|20140213|PEWAMO|MI|DENVER|CO|FT|45|1|FULL|0|Call|46000|||866-807-4968||DISPATCH, Dispatch|IANP@SUMMITTRANS.NET|SUMMIT TRANSPORTATION SERVICES INC.|
SUMMIT|L-delete|16490693|20140213|PEWAMO|MI|DENVER|CO|V|48|1|FULL|0|Call|44000|||866-807-4968||DISPATCH|IANP@SUMMITTRANS.NET|SUMMIT TRANSPORTATION SERVICES INC.|
SUMMIT|L-delete|16490699|20140214|PEWAMO|MI|DENVER|CO|V|48|1|FULL|0|Call|44000|||866-807-4968||DISPATCH|IANP@SUMMITTRANS.NET|SUMMIT TRANSPORTATION SERVICES INC.|
megacorpwv|L-Delete|16491928|20140214|WAITE PARK|MN|DOLTON|IL|R||1|FULL|0|CALL|0|0|(859) 538-1660  x2007|877-670-2837|||snewman@megacorplogistics.com|MEGACORP LOGISTICS 03|
```

My log shows this: As you see I manually put a comma in one field on the first record and it acted as a seperator

```
2014-02-13 12:29:41 ERROR -- Blank Email 
2014-02-13 12:29:41 ERROR -- undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
2014-02-13 12:29:41 DEBUG -- Email IANP@SUMMITTRANS.NET
2014-02-13 12:29:42 DEBUG -- Email IANP@SUMMITTRANS.NET
2014-02-13 12:29:42 DEBUG -- Email snewman@megacorplogistics.com
```

Comment: You attempted, so it is good. But could you give some more samples data, and expected output?

Comment: If your CSV is |-delimited why can't you do `CSV.read("file", :col_sep => '|')` at the very beginning?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're only parsing the first element of the array "h" and "line".  Try removing the "[0]" from those two lines.  It's not that the email is blank it's that everything except Member_ID is blank.

```
header = CSV.parse_line(h, { :col_sep => "|" } )
lines.each do |line|
fields = CSV.parse_line(line,{:col_sep => "|"})
```

Ah. OK. Phillip Hallstrom has identified the problem.  It's in the CSV.read statement.  By default CSV.read will attempt to delimited by comma ",".  What CSV.read is attempting to do is read each line as an array element and then parse each line into another array.  Therefore, if your file looks like this:

```
a|b|c|d|e
apple|ball, bearing|cantelope|date|elephant
```

It will return the following array on CSV.read

```
[["a|b|c|d|e"], ["apple|ball", " bearing|cantelope|date|elephant"]]
```

You can see that CSV.read is attempting to do the full parse before you get the opportunity to specify a delimiter.

Either read the lines in using normal file I/O or recode to specify the delimiter in the CSV.read statement

Comment: i added my full coding to the posting so you can see i am trying to parse everything was just tring to debug it

Comment: it works perfectly without the Comma but with the Comma it errors